# Xamarin iOS PrepareForSegue gets not called

Tags: .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I'm having some problems navigating from a UITableViewController to a UIViewController.

What I am trying to do is make an application that allows the user to search for parts within SAP and display them in a simple table. Once the user clicks on one row, a detail page should open.

Unfortunately the navigation is not working and I have no idea why. I'm using a storyboard containing a UINavigationController -> UITableViewController -> UIViewController.

I set up the segue from my UITableViewController to the detail page (UIViewController) by hitting the control key within Visual Studio 2015 Designer and drawing a line from the TableCell to my UIViewController. I see that the table cell gets a fat blue border.

After this is set the segue identifier to "PartDetailSegue". On my UITableViewController I have overwritten the PrepareForSegue function.

When I add a breakpoint to PrepareForSegue function and launch the application, the function does not get invoked when I click on the table cell. Is there anything I missing?

[Xamarin Designer Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySL0I.jpg)

Code in my UITableViewContoller

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
        {
            if (segue.Identifier == "PartDetailSegue")
            {
                var navctlr = segue.DestinationViewController as PartDetailViewcontroller;
                if (navctlr != null)
                {
                    var rowPath = TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow;
                    var item = ((PartsTableViewDataSource)TableView.Source).GetItem(rowPath.Row);
                    navctlr.SetPart(this, item);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Latest updates for Xamarin are installed.

Comment: Is the segue happening (does the UIViewController get pushed)? If not, I would try to trigger it manually by overriding `RowSelected` and call `this.PerformSegue("PartDetailSegue", this);` to fire the segue and see if the segue works correctly. (`this` will be the `UITableViewController` instance). I'm guessing that something is configured incorrectly in the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for your respond! The seque is happening when i call it via  this.PerformSegue("PartDetailSegue", this); I already tiried. So the seque seems to be setup correctly. On my storryboard the UITableViewController is linked to my own class that inherits form UITableViewController and overrides the PrepareForSeque function. The seque identifier is also set.

Comment: I just tried this using Xamarin Studio with a storyboard, and it all worked as expected. So it **should** work in VS. Are you certain that you selected the "Selection Segue" "Show" option? You might try creating the segue with Xamarin Studio and see if there is a bug in VS.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear you resolved it.

Comment: I found the problem!. The UITableView has this "Prototype" TableViewCell whre the seque is started from. In my UITableViewSource, in GetCell function i return new cells and setting the cell identifier to "TableCell". Since in the designer the Prototype TableViewCell has no identifier set, it seems that cell that gets added through my datasource has no knowledge about the segue. After setting the identifier in the designer it worked! Unfortunately this is not documented on Xamrain website. Thanks for you help!

Comment: If you use the prototype cell, you really shouldn't be creating new cells in `GetCell`. Instead you should use `DequeueReusableCell("CellIdentifier", indexPath)` on `tableView`. Reusing cells is a good performance optimization. If you want to use a custom cell class, just assign that class to your prototype cell in the storyboard. And be sure to set the cell's reuse identifier in the storyboard and use that in your dequeue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a UITableViewSource and create cells in GetCell function via DequeueReusableCell("SomeName"), make sure in the storyboard the prototype table view cell has set the same identifier. Otherwiese DequeueReusableCell wont return the template of your prototype cell, that is aware of the segue.